# Pow does not change ruby version after project upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, rack-pow

I use Pow and powify gem with my rails project.

Now I try to upgrade my ruby version (from 1.9.3 to 2.0.0, I use RVM)

When I switch ruby version, install all gem dependencies, I make sure that app works fine by running `rails s` and visiting `localhost:3000`

Previosly I browse my app by visiting `http://my_app.dev` with pow. After upgrade this url doesn't work due to error `Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch: Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0`

What I tried:

- recreate pow application
- restart pow server
- update pow server
- kill pow server
- google this error :)

This error still exists. By the way, I have another rails app, that uses ruby 2.0 initially and works with pow ok.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create an file called `.powrc` in your projects root directory. Copy and paste the content below to your file.

```
if [ -f "$rvm_path/scripts/rvm" ]; then
  source "$rvm_path/scripts/rvm"

  if [ -f ".rvmrc" ]; then
    source ".rvmrc"
  fi

  if [ -f ".ruby-version" ]; then
    rvm use `cat .ruby-version`
  fi

  if [ -f ".ruby-gemset" ]; then
    rvm gemset use --create `cat .ruby-gemset`
  fi
fi
```

This will look to your ruby environment files and select the correct version from it. If this won't work on your first try then make sure you have an `.rvmrc` or `.ruby-version` file in your root directory for the project.

And don't forget to `touch tmp/restart.txt` to restart your application.

Source: https://gist.github.com/nbibler/5307941

Comment: I inattentively read pow manual :( I put such file in my `~` directory, but should in project directory. Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Copied the above code to `.powrc` in my project directory and touched `tmp/restart.txt` but still getting the exact same error (upgrading from Ruby 2.2.0 to 2.2.1 using the line `ruby` in my Gemfile)

Comment: @GeorgeMillo try creating a file called '.ruby-version' in your project root directory with the content '2.2.1'. Then try again.

Comment: I tried all this and it did not work. I tried rebooting, still not working. Waited a few minutes, still not working. Then I thought I would do something else and ran ```bundle exec rspec spec```, and then noticed that pow was now working. Not sure if it was the time delay or something to do with running the tests.

Comment: Yah same here @Obromios , I restarted, changed all the things, reinstalled rvm, reinstalled bundler, everything *everything* says the correct Ruby, but I still got the fail message. Then after a couple hours it started working. But unfortunately I do have to switch between Rubies often enough that I likely shouldn't be using POW anymore.

Comment: Also this script doesn't work, and the one on RVM's website crashes the site as well with an error.

Comment: @Trip this may be outdated by now, feel free to sugest an edit on my answer if you manage to solve the problem using anything like this.